# Laravel DB Migrations in custom package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have some experience in Laravel but I'm still learning (currently I'm using 5.4). I'm creating my own package (which will have its own database tables, but one of the tables will be related with the **users** table of the "main" application).

I know I can load the migrations on my Package's Service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/migrations');
}
```

But I see loads of pages/tutorials telling to publish those migration files. Is there any advantage on doing this?

Honestly I would prefer to keep the migration files inside the package, but I would like to know if there are any drawbacks on doing this before finishing my package and deploy it in production.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The user won't be able to execute them while they are not published :) is that reason enough to publish them?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @milo526. In the Laravel documentation says: "Once your package's migrations have been registered, they will automatically be run when the  php artisan migrate command is executed. You do not need to export them to the application's main database/migrations directory." To register the migrations, I just need to call loadMigrationsFrom as I've explained in my question.

Comment: Sorry you are right, my sources where outdated

Comment: As far as I understand, the point of publishing is to allow x user to make changes to migrations/views/etc without modifying the actual package, for instance the need of an extra column.